# Weblogic Active Connections Increasing

Tags: weblogic, datasource, connection

I deployed my project to weblogic, and I realized I had connections not closed because weblogic server went to overload.

I fixed them. But still I have same problem. In weblogic monitoring Active connections count is increasing but in database (Oracle) this connections are INVALID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is leak connections. To find them I did follow steps.

1. Services - Data Sources - MyDatasource - Connection Pool - Advanced, I set Inactive Connection Timeout = 15
2. Services - Datasources - MyDatasource - Diagnosticts, I checked Profile Connection Leak property.
3. Diagnostics - Log Files - MyServer's Data Source Log and I can see where there are leak connections.

After clean all leak conenctions in project, maybe it is good to set back Inactive Connection Timeout property.